# How to use colormaps to color plots of Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, colors, plot, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pd.DataFrame` like this one:

```
ColumnName
1
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
2
```

I can plot it with `df['ColumnName'].plot(style='o')`

How I can define different colors for the different values in the column (for example red for value 1, green for 2, orange for 3). I know it has to do with [`colormap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), but how I can use it?

An solution is to construct a new `DataFrame` with the columns of every value. But these values are sorted and I want have exactly this sequence just colored in the different colors.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To plot the first column from your dataframe, try something like this:

```
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20, size=20))
cmap = cm.get_cmap('Spectral') # Colour map (there are many others)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
# Now here's the plot. range(len(df)) just makes the x values 1, 2, 3...
# df[0] is then the y values. c sets the colours (same as y values in this
# case). s is the marker size.
ax.scatter(range(len(df)), df[0], c=df[0], s=120, cmap=cmap, edgecolor='None')
plt.show()
```

Which results in:[image: Plot output]

Comment: How do I specify custom colors to be used as a colormap? For example if I want to use only two custom colors as a colormap.

Comment: Now the command is cmap = cm.Spectral in the new version of matplolib

Comment: Further colormaps can be found there:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html