# Color time-series based on column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a time-series in a pandas DataFrame (`df.data` in the example) and want to color the plot based on the values of another column (`df.colors`in the example; values are 0, 1, and 2 in this case, but it would be good / more portable if it would also work with `float`s).

```
import pandas as pd
n = 10
seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"data":randn(n), "colors":randint(0,3,n)},
                  index=pd.date_range(start="2016-01-01", periods=n))

df.data.plot(style=".", ms=10)
```

[image: Uncolored time-series plot]

What I am looking for is something like

```
df.data.plot(style=".", color=df.colors)
```

(which does not work), in order to produce a plot like this:

[image: Colored time-series plot]

Here the markers are colored red, orange, and green, for `colors==0`, `1`, and `2`, respectively. It's relatively easy to do this manually for few data and few colors, but is there a straightforward way to do this automatically?

There seems to be a solution using `plt.scatter` and colormaps, as shown in the answer to [How to use colormaps to color plots of Pandas DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741214/how-to-use-colormaps-to-color-plots-of-pandas-dataframes), but using `plt.scatter` with a datetime index destroys the convenient automatic axis scaling of using `df.data.plot(...)`. Is there a way using this notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use [`DF.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and create a nested `dictionary` to specify the color values for the `int/float` values to be mapped against.

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
df.replace({'colors':{0:'red',1:'orange',2:'green'}}, inplace=True)
```

You could then perform [`DF.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on it to keep the colors same for each subgroup of the `groupby` object on every iteration step.

```
for index, group in df.groupby('colors'):
    group['data'].plot(style=".", x_compat=True, ms=10, color=index, grid=True)
```

[image]